# Syntax Error for using cursor in a stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, delimiter

I searched the whole website for answer but none of it solve my problem so I'm gona post my error with a new thread.

My code,

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `DB`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GET_Summary`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`connect`@`%` PROCEDURE `GET_Summary`(IN pDateFrom DATE,IN pDateTo DATE)

ROOT:BEGIN

    DECLARE pTotal,pShortCode,pSignUp,pUnSub,pJunk INT;
    DECLARE pCOM NVARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMOMain
    (GrandTotal INT,ShortCode INT,COM NVARCHAR(10),SignUp INT,UnSub INT, Junk INT);  

    DECLARE MoMainCur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT COUNT(*),shortcode,(CASE WHEN ComID= 1 THEN 'A'
    WHEN ComID= 2 THEN 'B' WHEN ComID= 3 THEN 'C' ELSE 'UV' END) AS COM
    FROM tbl_inbox 
    INNER JOIN tbl_keyword ON keywordid = recvkeyword 
    WHERE recvDate >='2011-11-15'  AND recvDate < '2011-11-16' 
    GROUP BY shortcode,COM;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET no_more_rows = TRUE;    

    OPEN MoMainCur;

    read_loop:LOOP
    FETCH MoMainCur INTO pTotal,pShortCode,pCOM ;

    INSERT INTO TMOMain
    VALUES
    (pTotal,pShortcode,pCOM ,0,0,0);
    IF no_more_rows THEN
        CLOSE MoMainCur;
        LEAVE the_loop;

    END LOOP;

    -- CLOSE MoMain;

    SELECT * FROM TMOMain;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

MYSQL version 5.1

ERROR Message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE MoMainCur CURSOR FOR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare.html):

> `DECLARE` is permitted only inside a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement and **must be at its start, before any other statements**.
>
> Declarations must follow a certain order. Cursors must be declared before declaring handlers. Variables and conditions must be declared before declaring cursors or handlers.

Emphasis mine.

Move your `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMOMain` to *after* all your `DECLARE`s.

Comment: thanks! it solved the problem. 1st time using mysql, so I didn't really bother bout the order. thanks!